# How to make the bot not try ban members above its role discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi im trying to make a ban command but I want it so if you try to ban a member above the bots role it doesn't get a error please help discord.js v12

Comment: You need to move the bot's role higher in the hierarchy. If someone has a higher role, even though the bot has ban permission, it can't ban the aforementioned person. That's how Discord works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the bot and the member's highest role position, and `return` if the member has a higher role.

Assuming the member you want to ban is stored in a variable called `member`:

```
if(member.roles.highest.position > message.guild.me.roles.highest.position) {
  return message.channel.send("This member has a role higher than mine!");
}
```